# Getting rid off the logarithms in an equation to simplify

Tags: logarithms

ok, I'm having trouble solving for equations when logarithms are involved.
I know a little bit about logarithm rules but in equations I'm lost.
example:

$$\frac{1}{b}\ln{y}=\frac{1}{a}\ln{x}+c$$

I can take  $b$ to the other side:
$$\ln{y}=\frac{b}{a}\ln{x}+bc$$

I know you can solve for $y$ by incorporating  $e$ to both sides of the equation. and there's where I have trouble with.

How you add $e$ to the right side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ln{y}=\frac{b}{a}\ln{x}+bc$$
$$\ln{y}=\frac{b}{a}\ln{x}+\ln(e^{bc})$$
$$\ln{y}=\ln{x^{\frac{b}{a}}}+\ln(e^{bc})$$
$$\ln{y}=\ln({x^{\frac{b}{a}}e^{bc}})$$
$${y}={x^{\frac{b}{a}}e^{bc}}$$

Comment: great explanation ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln y = \frac{b}{a}\ln x + bc$$

Note: $\ln p = q \implies p = e^q$

$$ y = e^{\frac{b}{a}\ln x + bc} = e^{\ln x^{\frac{b}{a}}}\cdot e^{bc}$$

$$ y = x^\frac{b}{a}e^{bc}$$

Note: $e^{\ln m} = m$